# angular2 universal is very unstable - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-universal

I am finding the starter repo from angular class very very unstable or just on how I am using it.  My code works locally hitting the same service as remote yet I get the below

I followed the rules

```
npm run build
npm start
```

The slightest error I get the below:

```
'Hash: 51619e5be8128fe9ed97eb75ce5c5bacf4f02ce1
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.22
Child
    Hash: 51619e5be8128fe9ed97
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.22
    Time: 18736ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.js  3.57 MB       0  [emitted]  main
     [320] ./src async 160 bytes {0} [built]
        + 544 hidden modules
Child
    Hash: eb75ce5c5bacf4f02ce1
    Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.22
    Time: 11670ms
       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.js  33.5 kB       0  [emitted]  main
        + 28 hidden modules

> universal-starter@2.0.0 start /var/test-starter
> npm run server


> universal-starter@2.0.0 server /var/test-starter
> nodemon dist/server/index.js

[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /var/test-starter/dist/**/* src/index.html
[nodemon] starting `node dist/server/index.js`
Listening on: http://localhost:3000
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null

/var/test-starter/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:140
                        throw error;
                        ^
Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How can this crash a server?  I have to kill and restart.

I use angular2 n production without issue.  angular2 universal is rather problematic.

How do I resolve gracefully?  Or am I not serving in production properly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems related with [angular/zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/) based on your error.

Try to back to **zone.js@0.6.21**. If it works, try to locate the codes which cause the issue and reproduce it and post at [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues).

Since zone.js@0.6.22, there are some new issues, such as https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/448